# Fork a worker under different user with Node.js cluster module?

Tags: node.js, process, fork, uid

How to fork a worker under different user with Node.js [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by populating [`cluster.settings`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_settings) object with `uid` property in master process. In my case it looks like this:

```
cluster.settings.uid = 10000;
```

where `10000` is my `uid`

To get your `uid` on Linux, run:

```
id -u <your-user-name-here>
```

or simply:

```
id -u
```